# Setting Google Chart LineChart options using series property

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I would like to change following options for my linechart
 when i do options as below it ignores the first series setting
 and does the second series property.

```
var options = {
    title: 'Temperature Graph ( samples every 30\' )',
    titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 16 },
    legend: { position: 'in' },

    series: {
        0: { pointSize : 2 },
        1: { pointSize : 0 }},
    series: {
        0: { lineWidth: 2 },
        1: { lineWidth: 1 }}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
series: {
    0: { pointSize : 2 , lineWidth : 2 },
    1: { pointSize : 0 , lineWidth : 1 }},
    pointShape : 'circle'
}
```